# Tuning infinispan/hibernate search indexing

Tags: indexing, hibernate-search, infinispan

Using

Infinispan 6.0.0
Hibernate Search 4.4.0

But indexing seems extremely slow.

Here are the jmx stats from the DefaultCacheManager...

averageReadTime: 0
averageWriteTime: 9903

I tried max_merge_docs and merge_factor and ram_buffer as indicated in the docs here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-configuration.html#d0e2031

But that seems to do nothing. The only thing that sort of works better is the number of shards...

```
<namedCache name="myCache">
    <clustering mode="distribution">
        <async/>
        <hash numOwners="1"/>
    </clustering>   

    <indexing enabled="true" indexLocalOnly="true">
        <properties>
            <property name="default.directory_provider" value="ram" />
            <property name="default.indexwriter.merge_factor" value="30000" />
            <property name="default.indexwriter.ram_buffer_size" value="1024" />
            <!--<property name="default.sharding_strategy.nbr_of_shards" value="4" />              -->
         </properties>
    </indexing>
</namedCache>
```

The values above are the last ones I tried. I tried different ones to no avail. Only nbr_of_shards seems to speed things up just a tad.

The model...

```
@Indexed
@ProvidedId
public class MyModel implements Serializable
{
    @DocumentId
    Integer id;
    Integer prop1;
    Integer prop2;
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    String prop3;
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    String prop4;
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    String prop5;
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    String prop6;
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    String prop7;
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    String prop9;
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    Long prop10;
}
```

And in my servlet doPost()

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
// Get POST params here and set the model properties...
cache.put(id, model);
out.println("Added!");
```

Comment: I've had similar issues with the indexing. I've an ongoing question at the Infinispan forum. https://community.jboss.org/thread/237385

Comment: Yeah I doubt you going to get far with it. I stopped looking at it for a while.

Comment: Did you stop using Infinispan or try another library like GridGain? GridGain recently open sourced v6. What is your usecase for Infinispan?

Comment: Stopped using it couldn't get to perform like I wanted same with Gridgain couldn't get it to perform like I wanted either. Gigaspaces did the trick but was quite expensive. That's based on my own personal testing. I'm sure the mentioned companies would argue differently but it really depends on your needs and testing.